# Does audio work in Zenbook 14x UX5401ZAS?

Tags: drivers, sound, laptop, asus, compatibility

Here it is in the hardware database: https://linux-hardware.org/?view=computers&vendor=ASUSTek+Computer&model=Zenbook+UX5401ZAS_UX5401ZAS

Audio chip is reported as Realtek ALC294.

Audio issues have been reported with Zenbooks and this audio chip.
I wanted to know, what's the state of affairs currently? Does it still not work?
Can anyone with this model or chip comment please?

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also Zenbook 14X OLED UX-5401ZA and sound works fine.
Also all works on Ubuntu 22.10 kernel 5.19.0-29-generic exept fingerprint and Fn+10 form Camera On-Off.
;) :)

---

akis61@akis61zenbook:~$ **lsusb**
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 13d3:5460 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1b3f:1167 Generalplus Technology Inc. GENERAL WEBCAM
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 13d3:3568 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 2109:8888 VIA Labs, Inc. USB Billboard Device
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0749 Genesys Logic, Inc. SD Card Reader and Writer
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

---

akis61@akis61zenbook:~$ **lspci**
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 02)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation RST VMD Managed Controller
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 02)
0000:00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 02)
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 02)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 02)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b8 (rev 01)
0000:00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bb (rev 01)
0000:00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
0000:56:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0000:57:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7922
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO

Comment: Finally i found this trick and my fingerprint

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint

My system run Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic with kernel 6.5.0-10-generic

W O R K S ! ! ! ! ! !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm1ig_VFxSs